# Getting Uncaught ReferenceError when passing to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I am trying to populate a form with data from a table based on buttonclick. I am passing the data into a javascript function.

```
<?php 
$sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT FacultyEducationalId, FacultyDegreeName, FacultyCollegeName, FacultyPassingYear FROM facultyeducationaltable WHERE FacultyId=".$_SESSION['userid']);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
?>
<tr class="info">
<td><?php echo $row['FacultyDegreeName'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['FacultyCollegeName'] ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['FacultyPassingYear'] ?> </td>
<td>
<button onclick="modifyEdu(<?php echo $row['FacultyEducationalId'].','.$row['FacultyDegreeName'].','.$row['FacultyCollegeName'].','.$row['FacultyPassingYear']; ?>)" id="modifyEdu" class="btn btn-primary">Modify</button>                                                                 
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

The function is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function modifyEdu(id, deg, uniname, passyear) {
var facultyeduid=parseInt(id);
var degname=deg;
var uniname=uniname;
var passyear=passyear;
console.log("1");
document.getElementById("degreename").value="2";
document.getElementById("universityname").value=uniname;
document.getElementById("passyear").value=passyear;
}
</script>
```

I am getting : Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick. How do I fix this? (x is the value that is in 'FacultyDegreeName')

Comment: well you do not wrap it in quotes it sounds like. View the source and you will see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to escape the string using single quote `'` and `\'`:

```
<button onclick="modifyEdu('<?php echo $row['FacultyEducationalId'].'\',\''.$row['FacultyDegreeName'].'\',\''.$row['FacultyCollegeName'].'\',\''.$row['FacultyPassingYear']; ?>')" id="modifyEdu" class="btn btn-primary">Modify</button>
```

Because you will get `modifyEdu(foo,bar,2018)` instead of `modifyEdu('foo','bar','2018')`.

In the first case `foo` will be considered as an undefined variable and cause the *"ReferenceError"* error.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. I had no idea this was the problem.